# Getting full dependency name in maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

How do i get full dependency name in maven plugin?
For now I'm using this function:

```
private String getDependencyFilename(final Dependency toBeResolved) {
    return toBeResolved.getArtifactId() + "-" + toBeResolved.getVersion() + "." + toBeResolved.getType();
}
```

And I'm wondering if there is any build-in function to do that.

Dependency class is described here: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Dependency.html

EDIT:
I didn't find good answer for now, so I'm using this code, maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
/**
 * Returns full name of dependency file format: artifactId-version-classifier.type , e.g.: simple-jboss-plugin-1.22-prod.jar
 * @param  dependency from which name will be extracted
 * @return the name of dependency file
 */
public static String getDependencyFilename(final Dependency dependency) {
    return dependency.getArtifactId() + "-" + dependency.getVersion()
            + resolveClassifier(dependency.getClassifier()) + "." + dependency.getType();
}

/**
 * Returns classifier with appended '-', or empty string if there is no classifier or if classifier is empty
 * @param classifier
 * @return resolved classifier string
 */
private static String resolveClassifier(final String classifier) {
    return Strings.isNullOrEmpty(classifier) ? "" : "-" + classifier;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried toBeResolved.getId() ?

Comment: No sir, I don't see that function in API.

Comment: where from is Dependency class?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Dependency.html